# Creating a Get_Next_Line function in C

Tags: c, string

I have to create a C function that returns a line read from a file descriptor. I have to define a macro `READ_SIZE` (that can be editable). This `READ_SIZE` indicates the number of characters to read at each call of read(). The number can only be positive. I also have to use one or several static variables to save the characters that were read but not sent back to the calling function. One .C file (5 functions max, 25 lines max per fonction) and one .h file ONLY. My function GNL shall return its return without the '\n'. If there is nothing more to read on the file descriptor, or if an error occur while reading, the function returns NULL.

Here is the prototype of the function:

```
char *get_next_line(const int fd)
```

FUNCTIONS ALLOWED: `malloc`, `free`, `read`, `write` (to use with `my_putchar`, `my_putstr`, etc).

Here is what I did so far, but really I don't have any ideas how to start it. If you have any clues to get me started, I'd really appreciate. I will be working on it for the next ten hours if I have to. I will come to check here and update on my progress really often. If you have any questions, ask me!

Here is the main file (that I'll remove before pushing my work):

```
#include "get_next_line.h"

void my_putchar(char c)
{
  write(1, &c, 1);
}

int my_strlen(char *str)
{
  int i;

  i = 0;
  while (str[i] != '\0')
    i++;
  return (i);
}

char *my_putstr(char *str)
{
  if (str == NULL)
    write(1, "(null)", 6);
  else
    write(1, str, my_strlen(str));
  return (str);
}

int main()
{
  char *s;

  while ((s = get_next_line(0)))
  {
    my_putstr(s);
    my_putchar('\n');
    free(s);
  }
  return (0);
}
```

And here is my get_next_line.c file so far:

```
int check_backslash(char *buff)
{
  int n;

  n = 0;
  while (buff[n])
  {
    if (buff[n] == '\n')
      return (n);
    n++;
  }
  return (0);
}

char *get_next_line(const int fd)
{
  int n;
  char *str_to_return;
  static int i = 0;
  static char buff[READ_SIZE];

  n = 0;
  while (n = 0)
  {
    if ((read(fd, buff, READ_SIZE)) == -1)
      return (NULL);
    n = check_backslash(buff);
  }
  return (str_to_return);
}
```

I already did some different things that I won't put on this subject, because I would like to start it fresh. I just need some clues to help me get started. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: What's wrong with `fgets` or `getline`?

Comment: @Olaf I have to recode it. It's a work. ;)

Comment: "I will come to check here and update on my progress really often.". Please don't do that. Stackoverflow is not Facebook. If you have a *specific* question then we are happy to help. If you then have further issues then they should be asked seperately in a new question. We don't really want FB update style commentary on your progress.

Comment: @kaylum oh alright sorry. So this question is fine, but if I do some progress and then I have another question, I create a new post?

Comment: Well, I don't actually think your question is fine. Because "where do I start" is not a very specific question. So I won't be answering it personally. But perhaps someone else may. SO works best if your question is specific. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) for some guidelines. In particular: "Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation"

Comment: @kaylum alright thanks a lot I will!

Comment: Also, don't remove part of your question "before pushing your code".  Doing so will make this question useless for anyone who comes across it in the future.  If there's a problem leaving your code attached to the question, then you shouldn't be posting it here in the first place.

Comment: Suggest google for readline.c,  copy the code into your new function, modify the code for your needs,

Comment: @bta No, I wanted to say "I will remove the main file" from the repo, cause I cannot push my main file. I just use the main file to test my function. I won't remove the code of this post, no worries ;)